# 1st option is selected by default in drop down list

Tags: php, jquery, html

1st option is selected by default in dropdown list .I want to deselect it.following is my code

```
<label>Select from below</label>
<div>
  <select name="subjects[]" class="ms"  id="subjects" class="form-control ">
    <option value=''>SELECT</option>
    <?php  foreach ($subjects as $s) {
      echo '<option value=' . $s->sb_id . '>' . $s->subject_name . '</option>';
    } ?>
  </select>
```

Now here "SELECT" is also being selected

Comment: That's how `select` elements work. Something *has* to be selected by default.

Comment: this is the default behaviour of select element

Comment: so what has to be done if i dont want anything to be selected

Comment: try this: `<option value=''></option>`

Comment: @PranilPagare then don't use a select. A list of radio buttons may be more suitable to your needs. If you tell us why you need this we may be able to help you more effectively.

Comment: as the others have said, this is expected default behaviour. Most people add a `<option value=''>--Please Select--</option>` to have no default

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i just did this <option disabled selected></option>.Will do for now.If help needed ,will post a qury.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```html
<label>Select from below</label>
<div>
  <select name="subjects[]" class="ms"  id="subjects" class="form-control ">
    <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">SELECT</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
  </select>
```